# Delete a line from Neo4j DB

Tags: neo4j

I have this little graph:

```
CREATE (Thing:Class {title:'Thing'})
CREATE (Places:Class{title:'Places'})
CREATE (Lemma:Class {title:'Lemma'})
CREATE (Country:Class {title:'Country'})
CREATE (Region:Class {title:'Region'})
CREATE (loc1:Index {title:'loc00001'})
CREATE (loc1_1:Index {title:'loc00001.01'})
CREATE (Abc:Placename {title:'Abc', gender:'n'})
CREATE
  (Thing)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Places),
  (Thing)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Lemma),
  (Places)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Country),
  (Country)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Region),
  (Country)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Region),
  (Places)-[:HAS_INDIVID]->(loc1),
  (loc1)-[:HAS_LA_VAR]->(loc1_1),
  (loc1_1) -[:HAS_VAR_NAME]->(Abc)
```

I made a mistake, defining  (Country)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Region) relationship 2 times. 
If I run this query:

```
MATCH (n { title: 'Country'})-[r]-() DELETE n,r
```

It will delete all Country-related nodes and all HAS_SUBCLASS relationships, which is kinda the half of my little DB. 
Is there a way to just delete 1 line in the DB without this loss?

At this point I can easily delete all nodes and rels from my DB - to clean it completely, and to rebuild everything from the scratch. But later, when I will have thousands of entries this way of correcting mistakes would be too time consuming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below.   Keep in mind the relationship IDs will be different for you, but this is to illustrate.

OK, so first let's figure out which relationship is duplicated (see comment on other answer)

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:Class {title:"Country"})-[r:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Region:Class {title:"Region"}) return r;      
+-----------------------+
| r                     |
+-----------------------+
| :HAS_SUBCLASS[9170]{} |
| :HAS_SUBCLASS[9171]{} |
+-----------------------+
2 rows
7 ms
```

Now query for just one of those relationships to demonstrate....

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ start r=relationship(9170) return r;
+-----------------------+
| r                     |
+-----------------------+
| :HAS_SUBCLASS[9170]{} |
+-----------------------+
1 row
204 ms
```

Now delete just the first one.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ start r=relationship(9170) delete r;
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Relationships deleted: 1
16 ms
```

Now demonstrate that the original query now only returns 1 relationship.

```
    neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:Class {title: "Country"})->[r:HAS_SUBCLASS)   Region:Class                                                                                 match (n:Class {title:"Country"})-[r:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Region:Class {title:"Region"}) return r;
+-----------------------+
| r                     |
+-----------------------+
| :HAS_SUBCLASS[9171]{} |
+-----------------------+
1 row
11 ms
```

Comment: thank you, that looks like what I need! I will try it out once I have this problem again))

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the label to narrow it down just to the Class whose title="Country".  Here:

In my neo4j-shell, it goes like this with your test data:

```
$ MATCH (n:Class { title: 'Country'})-[r]-() DELETE n,r;
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 1
Relationships deleted: 3
```

Note that when you delete a node, all incident relationships have to go.

This works given the data sample you've provided.

Now one other thing -- you're not creating many differentiating properties on those nodes.  If you have a data set where this query matches more than one node:

```
MATCH (n:Class { title: "Country" }) return n;
```

Then your nodes are probably just defined too broadly.  If you want to delete only one such node, you'll need the node's ID, or some other property that makes it different from other nodes.

Comment: My query deleted exactly the same number of nodes and relationships. I don't want to delete specific nodes, but only one redundant line, difining a relationship  (Country)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Region)

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean with "one redundant line"?  Do you mean one line of the cypher you provided above?  The trouble with your cypher above is that it only defines one property per node.  So if you find things by that property, it might not be selective enough.

Comment: I mean I have added my mistake 2 lines that are the same:   (Country)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Region),
(Country)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Region)
I was wondering how I can simply correct this mistake without destroying half of the database